# Array of generics in Java, enforce all to be the same type?

Tags: java, generics

Just playing around with generics and stuff in Java, came across a potential issue. Here is a simplified version of what I was thinking

```
public class Test<T> {
    private T[] arrayOfGenerics;
    int top;

    public Test(int size) {
        arrayOfGenerics = (T[]) new Object[size];
        top = 0;
    }

    public void add(T toAdd) {
        arrayOfGenerics[top++] = toAdd;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test myTest = new Test(10);
        myTest.add("Some String");  //First value added is a String
        myTest.add(12);             //Way to make this NOT work, since myTest should only accept Strings now
    }

}
```

Obviously this doesn't have much use, production wise, but I was thinking for more complicated data structures where you wanted to have the flexibility of generics but still enforce them all having to be of the same type. Which is a horrible way of explaining it, but going back to the example code above, would there be a way to make it so that, when someone instantiated and instance of Test, they had to specify the type of `arrayOfGenerics` and be stuck with it, either through the constructor somehow, or maybe just based on the first type of value that is added?

Another way to explain it, say you were implementing your own Stack or LinkedList data structure. You want it to be a Stack of all of the same kind of Object. It can be Strings, Integers, whatever, but it has to 'pick' one and stick with it.

Comment: You are currently using a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Try `Test<String> test = new Test<>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not using the generics effectively here. For ex. doing the following:

```
// With this statement, the types that can be contained in the
// instance is fixed now.
Test<String> myTest = new Test<>(10);
myTest.add("Some String"); // this will work
myTest.add(12);  // this won't compile
```

You did declare the `Test` to have a generic type, but, in your original code, you didn't make use of it while constructing the instance. Which effectively results in an instance of a `Test<Object>`.

In Java, the generics were retrofitted, and since they didn't want to break backward compatibility, they had to allow construction of "raw" instances. However, the compiler should still give you warnings about "raw types" and probably an IDE would ask you to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to make it explicit that you are using non-parameterized types.

As for enforcing the user to make sure that they are putting in correct type, the best you can do is runtime checking. That is, for ex. the constructor can take a `Class` as an argument. And in all the methods, you make sure that the given arguments are of correct type. But this doesn't give you compile time checking. Errors will only be known at runtime.

Another thing is that, once you have made sure that you designed your API correctly using the generics, you probably shouldn't worry about enforcing the types. If the users of the API do not want to use specific types, regardless of the warnings by the compiler, maybe they do indeed want to use a raw-type (or, maybe, they don't know better and they haven't read [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)). Even Java's own APIs don't make any additional efforts in that area. For ex. the following code works, and doesn't throw any exceptions at run-time:

```
List list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("xyz");
list.add(123);
```

Comment: Well that works, yes, but that relies on the person instantiating the class to specify the type. Is there a way to enforce that requirement within the class itself?

Answer (score 0):

> **You have to specify the `Generic` type as `Test<String> myTest = new Test<>(10);` for the class if you want to make the whole class
>   contains same type of objects.**

Then your class cannot add other type of `Objects`. See following example.

```
Test<String> myTest = new Test(10);
```

1. `myTest.add("Some String"); //works fine`
2. `myTest.add(12);  //not works`

**You have set the size of the array at the `Constructor`. So you cannot exceed the specified size.** Do following modifications to make the size random.

```
//constructor
public Test() {
    top = 0;
    arrayOfGenerics = (T[]) new Object[top];
}

//add method
public void add(T toAdd) {
    top++;
    T[] newArray = (T[]) new Object[top];
    newArray[top - 1] = toAdd;
    System.arraycopy(arrayOfGenerics, 0, newArray, 0, top - 1);
    arrayOfGenerics = newArray;
}
```